# SIGBRT error in Objective-C, possibly from an attempted JSON request

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm having trouble with a simple JSON request in Objective-C. It gives me this error when I try to execute the code:

```
2015-08-11 12:11:15.552 WordADay[11482:1877243] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x7fa4d8e87270> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key text.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c01bc65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010bcb4bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c01b8a9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010b8da82a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] + 226
    4   Foundation                          0x000000010b833b23 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 251
    5   WordADay                            0x000000010b7823f2 -[ViewController getNewWord] + 1442
    6   WordADay                            0x000000010b781e09 -[ViewController viewDidLoad] + 73
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010c5451d0 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 738
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010c5453ce -[UIViewController view] + 27
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010c460289 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 58
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010c46064f -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 247
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010c46cde1 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010c410417 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2732
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010c41319e -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1349
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010c412095 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    15  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010ebd55e5 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 21
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bf4f41c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bf45165 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bf44f25 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bf44366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010c411b02 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010c4148c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    22  WordADay                            0x000000010b782aaf main + 111
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010e5bf145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

When I don't try to do this weird JSON request, it executes just fine... but when I do, it throws that error. I'm wondering what I should do... here is the code behind the JSON request:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  WordADay
//
//  Created by Lucas Steuber on 8/11/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Lucas Steuber. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *word;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *definition;

@end

@implementation ViewController
- (IBAction)newWord:(id)sender {
    [self getNewWord];
}

- (IBAction)moreInfo:(id)sender {

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self getNewWord];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)getNewWord {
    NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *filePath = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"dictionary" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    NSArray *values = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];


    NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % [values count];
    NSString *word = values[randomIndex];

    NSString *urlp1 = @"http://api.wordnik.com:80/v4/word.json/";
    NSString *urlp2 = @"/definitions?limit=1&includeRelated=true&sourceDictionaries=wiktionary&useCanonical=false&includeTags=false&api_key=a2a73e7b926c924fad7001ca3111acd55af2ffabf50eb4ae5";
    NSURL *wordnik = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@%@", urlp1, word, urlp2]];

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:wordnik
                                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                            timeoutInterval:30];
    // Fetch the JSON response
    NSData *urlData;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;
    NSError *jsonArrayError;
    NSString *desc;

    // Make synchronous request
    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                    returningResponse:&response
                                                error:&error];

    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: urlData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &jsonArrayError];

    if (!jsonArray) {
        NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", jsonArrayError);
    } else {
        NSArray *items = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:0];
        for (NSDictionary *item in items){
            desc = [item valueForKey:@"text"];
        }
    }


    self.word.text = word;
    self.definition.text = desc;
}
@end
```

I'm very new to Objective-C, and so far I don't really enjoy it.

**Edit:** Here's the JSON I'm parsing:

```
[{"textProns":[],"sourceDictionary":"wiktionary","exampleUses":[],"relatedWords":[],"labels":[],"citations":[],"word":"hello","partOfSpeech":"interjection","attributionText":"from Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License","attributionUrl":"http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/","text":"A greeting (salutation) said when meeting someone or acknowledging someone’s arrival or presence.","score":0.0}]
```

Comment: Update your question with the JSON (at least a sample) you are loading. The error indicates that your array contains strings, not dictionaries which is why the line `desc = [item valueForKey:@"text"];` is causing the crash.

Comment: BTW - learning to debug such crashes is a critical skill. Please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: @rmaddy I added the JSON

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is an array containing one dictionary. But your code is assuming a different structure. The following should match the actual data format:

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: urlData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &jsonArrayError];

if (!jsonArray) {
    NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", jsonArrayError);
} else {
    for (NSDictionary *item in jsonArray){
        desc = item[@"text"];
    }
}
```

But it makes no sense to iterate over one dictionary so it can be simplified to just:

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: urlData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &jsonArrayError];

if (!jsonArray) {
    NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", jsonArrayError);
} else {
    NSDictionary *item = [jsonArray firstObject];
    desc = item[@"text"];
}
```

Also note that you shouldn't be using `valueForKey:` to get a value from an `NSDictionary`. Use `objectForKey:` or modern syntax (like I did in my code here).